# How do I add a new driver to the debian installer in Debian Squeeze?

Tags: debian-squeeze, broadcom, debian

I am using a 10GB Broadcom NetExtreme II card in a supermicro system.  As it turns out the Wheezy version of this driver has a nasty bug in it that has a race condition that causes the driver to panic dump (and sometimes kernel panic).  I downlaoded the latest driver and tried to compile it against 3.2, but could not get it to work.  When I downgraded to Squeeze, we were able to compile the driver and get it to work. However, the debian-installer for Squeeze doesn't have a driver for the NIC, so we cannot PXE boot and provision over the network.

How can I add the driver module (bnx2x) to the debian installer kernel or initramfs so I can PXE boot and provision over the network?